# Apportioning data into new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Morning,

I am quite new to SQL Server 2008 so I was wondering if you could help me.

I currently have:

```
SELECT 
    c.code, d.date, d.date_previous, 
    CAST(d.date-date_previous as int) AS Days, 
    d.units, d.cost    
FROM table1 AS d    
INNER JOIN table2 AS p ON d.ID = p.ID    
INNER JOIN table3 AS c ON p.c_id = c.ID    
WHERE date_previous > '31/12/2012'
```

This is bringing back one row per invoice received after 31/12/2012. The aim is to get the following columns:

Code Jan data Feb data Mar data etc...

- one unique code per line (so I'm assuming row partitioning is required)
- Where a bill has a period of 3 months with, for example, 300 units, I'd like that separated out across 3 months (100 in each)

I'm aware I'd probably need to use a pivot function and some temp tables but I'm not that advanced yet.

Comment: Do you mean SQL-Server 2008? That's not MySQL.

Comment: Yes SQL server.  The pivot link helps but I still cant get the columns to apportion units per month?

Comment: I didn't notice the part about splitting a row with a long period into different columns. I'm not really sure how to do that part, so I've reopened the question.

Comment: where are you setting the alias of "p"?

Comment: @VikingBlooded `INNER JOIN table2 AS p`

Comment: Will need to know more about the data.

Comment: ah shit, sorry completely missed it.